# Using density in stat_bin with factor variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

It seems density plot in stat_bin doesn't work as expected for factor variables. The density is 1 for each category on y-axis.

For example, using diamonds data:

```
diamonds_small <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
ggplot(diamonds_small, aes(x = cut)) +  stat_bin(aes(y=..density.., fill=cut))
```

[image]

I understand I could use

```
stat_bin(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..), fill=cut))
```

to make it work. However, according to the docs of stat_bin, it should works with categorical variables.

Comment: `density` will make the area under each curve (i.e. each factor level) equal to one which is what you're seeing here.  Generally, density is used for continuous variables to get a smooth picture of the data.  In stead, you can use `geom_histogram` or something of that nature.

Comment: @Justin: Doesn't geom_histogram also use stat_bin, so it should have the same behaviour?

Comment: @JoakimLundborg I think it does, but it has some sensible defaults and  I generally try to stay away from using the `stat` functions directly and instead use the `geoms`.  The biggest issue was the `..density..` coupled with grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get what you (might) want by setting the `group` aesthetic manually.

```
ggplot(diamonds_small, aes(x = cut)) +  stat_bin(aes(y=..density..,group=1))
```

However, you can't easily fill differently within a group.  You can summarize the data yourself:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(diamonds_small,.(cut),
         function(x) data.frame(dens=nrow(x)/nrow(diamonds_small)))
ggplot(dd_dens,aes(x=cut,y=dens))+geom_bar(aes(fill=cut),stat="identity")
```

A *slightly* more compact version of the summarization step:

```
as.data.frame.table(prop.table(table(diamonds_small$cut)))
```

Comment: Where did you find that group=1 aes? It is not documented that it is used by stat_bin afaics.

Comment: I don't know specifically: it's pretty generically used throughout ggplot. While I love the package, I don't generally find the ggplot docs spectacularly helpful ...